# About Hibernate Batchsize ordering

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, batch-file

I new in Hibernate, but I have a question about @Batchsize annotation working. I understand how it works, but I don't understand how it grouping entity id's for select. For example - I have 2 classes: Car and Wheel. Car have List of Wheel and it must be empty. I create 10 cars - 5 of which have a List of Wheel and 5 of which doesn't. Then I run simple code

```
    List<Car> cars = session.createQuery("from Car").list();
    for (Car car : cars) {
        List<Wheel> wheels = car.getWheels();
        for (Wheel wheel : wheels) {
            System.out.println(wheel.getTitle());
        }
    }
```

After that I see something like this in my console:

```
Hibernate: 
select
    wheels0_.car_id as car3_1_,
    wheels0_.id as id1_,
    wheels0_.id as id0_0_,
    wheels0_.title as title0_0_ 
from
    Wheel wheels0_ 
where
    wheels0_.car_id in (
        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
    )
17:50:35,505 TRACE LongType:151 - binding '25' to parameter: 1<br>
17:50:35,505 TRACE LongType:151 - binding '18' to parameter: 2<br>
17:50:35,505 TRACE LongType:151 - binding '17' to parameter: 3<br> 
17:50:35,506 TRACE LongType:151 - binding '20' to parameter: 4<br> 
17:50:35,506 TRACE LongType:151 - binding '23' to parameter: 5<br>
```

But in next time i get others bindings. It can be 1, 15, 23, and others. But I misunderstand - how hibernate select id's for IN statement? Why it's not ordered by ASC or DESC(for example - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)?

Answer (score 1):

It's the order in which the car list is populated. If you want ascending order by id you could do something like: `List<Car> cars = session.createQuery("from Car order by id asc").list();`

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about the order of cars, then, as tibtof mentioned, simply modify your original query to add an `order by` clause so you iterate through cars in order.

If you're concerned about the order of Wheels in each List (e.g. for `Car1.getWheels()`, Wheel1 must come before Wheel2), BatchSize does not give you a sorting option. Consider making your Wheel class [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) and adding a convenience method, like getSortedWheels()

```
public List<Wheel> getSortedWheels() {
    List<Wheel> wheels = getWheels();
    Collections.sort(wheels);
    return wheels;
}
```